# WordPress Newspaper theme Post Loop 2 ( Pagination) Next page icon show all the the homepage content. How to show only Post loop Section

Tags: css, wordpress, loops, post, customization

In the WordPress Newspaper theme, there's a feature called 'Post Loop 2' which handles pagination for displaying multiple posts on the homepage. When users click on the 'Next Page' icon, it currently loads all the content from the homepage, rather than just the section dedicated to the post loop.

What I'm aiming for is to modify this behavior so that when users click on the 'Next Page' icon, it only shows the content within the designated post loop section. This means that instead of seeing all the content from the homepage, users would only see the posts that belong to the specific post loop section

I appreciate any guidance or insights on how to implement this functionality effectively

However, despite my efforts, I found that the 'Next Page' icon continued to load all the content from the homepage, rather than just the content within the post loop section.

Please Check my problem : https://youtu.be/EPvVp96oE2c

Comment: please include all the details here and fulfill the [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.